# ssh-add "Error connecting to agent: Connection refused"

Tags: ssh

My MacBook rebooted and when it does that I have to typically add my private key via ssh-add, using the following command

```
$ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And I never have any issues,
Today I am getting this error

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Error connecting to agent: Connection refused
```

What may be causing this? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Start the `ssh-agent` by running

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

in your terminal window.

Answer (score 20):

I'm using `iTerm2` on mac, I just `Session` -> `Restart session`

Comment: While the accepted answer didn't work for me, this one did.  Note that restarting session doesn't close your tabs/windows, but merely affects the state of currently active one.

Comment: I use iTerm2, but this didn't work for me because I was inside a tmux session. However, it did lead me to the correct solution. Killing tmux did the trick.